# Difference between covariance matrix and covariance operator

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

We that gaussian measures are characterized by their mean and covariance.In $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ we know that mean would be a vector of 1xn dimensions and covariance would be a nxn matrix.Now when we use a banach space or a hilbert space , mean will be an infinite vector and covariance will change to covariance operator.Can someone give me the notion of the difference between covariance matrix and covariance operator ?? I mean covariance operator is going to be an infinite dimensions matrix ?? What do we change from matrix to operator ??

Comment: Let $B$ Banach space and $\mu$ a Gaussian measure on $B$. The covariance operator is a bilinear map $C:B^* \times B^* \to \Bbb R$ defined by $C(f,g) = \int_B fg \;d\mu$. Equivalently, it is the operator from $B^* \to B^{**}$ defined by $f \mapsto (g \mapsto C(f,g))$. This is bounded by Fernique's theorem. In finite dimensional Hilbert spaces $H$, you can reconcile this with covariance matrix because you can choose basis $\{e_i\}$ for $H=H^*$, and the entries of the matrix $\bf C$ will just be $C(e_i,e_j)$. In this case you can write $C(f,g) = \bf f^t C g$.

Comment: Thank you very much , but this made me think , how we are going to find the entries of the covariance operator ?? We know from $\langle Ce_{i},e_{i} \rangle =\lambda_{i}$ witch is the eigenvalue , so we can find the whole diagonal.But how we are supposed to find $\lambda_{i,j}$ , the first thing that comes to my mind is $\langle Ce_{i},e_{j} \rangle $ but I don't trully know if I'm correct.

Comment: @shalop Thank you for yoru comment, even though it wasn't my question :) Could you please cite a resource for it that's publicly available. I've scoured the internet but Gaussian measure and distribution on Banach or Hilbert spaces seem not a very popular topic and the resources seem hard to find.

Comment: @LearningMath Well it was not your question in the first place. Try "Introduction to Stochastic PDE" by Martin Hairer. See Section 3.